# styled-components causing different behaviour

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

I made this [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/jn74x5v07w) to show the problem.
The thing is, when typing anything into first inputfield, it doesn't work because it is wrapped in a styled component. The second works because it is not wrapped. Why this? Appreciate any explanation.

```
const Wrapper = styled.div`
  padding: 15px;
`;
return (
  <div>
    <Wrapper>
      <AsyncTypeahead
        ... // <= does not work, because of "Wrapper"
      />
    </Wrapper>
    <AsyncTypeahead
      ... // <= works, because no "Wrapper"
    />
  </div>
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the wrapper definition outside of the class, it should not be called on each render, it actually generates a React component and has to be defined only once.

Here is an [updated and working version of your sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/2zv8mm2zjj).

Comment: Awesome, thanks. Misused this couple of times I guess.

Comment: That's what we're here for ;-)
But if you noticed, all the examples do it outside of the class